# Value of http body has no member request

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

Code:

```
let request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request1.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let values = ["name":"sfsd"]


        request1.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])

       .request(request1)
            .responseJSON { response in
                // do whatever you want here
                switch response.result {
                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    print(error)
                case .Success(let responseObject):
                    print(responseObject)
                }
        }
```

I am trying to send json value through POST method
At HttpBody line it is showing error "value of http body has no member request".What is wrong with my code?any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the method `request` on the object returned from `dataWithJSONObject`, which is an instance of NSData, and NSData does not have such a method. Use `Alamofire.request(request1)`